# MVC - After Data is posted some are not sent by model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have one view where is displaying some data, but some data are hidden using html type for hiding input. When I check developer console I see all data in payload, but when I check method in Controller certain data are null even if their values exist in payload, why ?
Here print screen from debugging.

[image]
**Updates**

View code

```
@model List<ImportSheepViewModel>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <form method="post" asp-action="PostSheep" asp-controller="Sheep">
            <table class="table table-responsive">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>BirthDate</th>
                    <th>Race</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Father</th>
                    <th>Mother</th>
                    <th>BoxDescription</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Model[i].HasError)
                    {
                        <tr class="alert alert-danger">
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Code
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Code"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].BirthDate
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BirthDate"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Gender
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Gender"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Race
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].RaceId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Race"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Father
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].FatherId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Father"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Mother
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].MotherId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Mother"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].BoxDescription
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BoxId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BoxDescription"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].HasError"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <tr class="alert alert-success">
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Code
                                <input type="hidden"  asp-for="@Model[i].Code"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].BirthDate
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BirthDate"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Gender
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Gender"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Race
                                <input type="hidden"  asp-for="@Model[i].RaceId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Race"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Father
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].FatherId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Father"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].Mother
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].MotherId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].Mother"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Model[i].BoxDescription
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BoxId"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].BoxDescription"/>
                                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].HasError"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Import Data" class="btn btn-success"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

ViewModelCode

```
  public class ImportSheepViewModel
    {
        public ImportSheepViewModel()
        {
            HasError = false;
        }
       public string Code { get; set; } 
       public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
       public string Race { get; set; }
       public string Gender { get; set; }
       public string Father { get; set; }
       public string Mother { get; set; }
       public string BoxDescription { get; set; }
       public bool HasError { get; private set; }
       public string BoxId { get; private set; }
       public string FatherId { get; private set; }
       public string MotherId { get; private set; }
       public string RaceId { get; private set; }
       public Gender FinalGender { get; set; }

       public void Validate()
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Race)
                                          || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Gender)
                                          || string.IsNullOrEmpty(BoxDescription))
               HasError = true;

           var gender = Gender.ToLower();
           if (gender != "male")
           {
               if (gender != "female")
                   HasError = true;
           }

       }

       public void SetBoxId(string boxId)
       {
           BoxId = boxId;
       }

       public void SetFatherId(string fatherId)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fatherId))
               FatherId = null;
           FatherId = fatherId;
       }
       public void SetMotherId(string motherId)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(motherId))
               MotherId = null;
           MotherId = motherId;
       }

       public void SetRaceId(string raceId)
       {
           RaceId = raceId;
       }

       public void SetError()
       {
           HasError = true;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I bet that the datatypes in controller differ from the ones in the payload for the null ones

Comment: No, data types are the same.I used same class for display and post data...

Comment: Can you share it, please?

Comment: I manage update of question, please check the code

Comment: Ok, you got a bunch of **private** setters (and managed via a method), so  the deserializer can't set the values on the payload

Comment: Just one clarification , based on your question , Are you sending data to view or receiving data from view?

Comment: @Ranjith.V both. What I'm doing is uploading file, check the data which are inside of the file, and with viewmodel send to view so user can understand if everything is fine or there are some errors. Than same viewmodel is sending to another method of controller in order to post data to database. When I changed to have public setters everything start work. Thanks J.Salas.